# hardhat simple storage. Getting ProviderError: Must be authenticated!

Tags: solidity, etherjs

**I am going through freecodecamp's course on fullstack web3 development. Can anyone help me with this error. Am not able to resolve this issue[image].  **

```
Deploy.js code : 
// imports
const { ethers, run, network } = require("hardhat");

// async main
async function main() {
  const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage");
  console.log("Deploying contract...");
  const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy();
  await simpleStorage.deployed();
  console.log(`Deployed contract to: ${simpleStorage.address}`);
  // what happens when we deploy to our hardhat network?
  if (network.config.chainId === 11155111 && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
    console.log("Waiting for block confirmations...");
    await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(6);
    await verify(simpleStorage.address, []);
  }

  const currentValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve();
  console.log(`Current Value is: ${currentValue}`);

  // Update the current value
  const transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.store(7);
  await transactionResponse.wait(1);
  const updatedValue = await simpleStorage.retrieve();
  console.log(`Updated Value is: ${updatedValue}`);
}

const verify = async (contractAddress, args) => {
  console.log("Verifying contract...");
  try {
    await run("verify:verify", {
      address: contractAddress,
      constructorArguments: args,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
      console.log("Already Verified!");
    } else {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
};

// main
main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

hardhat.config.js code:

````
require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox')
require('dotenv').config()
require('hardhat-gas-reporter')
require('solidity-coverage')

const COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY = process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY || ''
const SEPOLIA_RPC_URL =
  process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL ||
  'https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/your-api-key'
const PRIVATE_KEY =
  process.env.PRIVATE_KEY ||
  '0x11ee3108a03081fe260ecdc106554d09d9d1209bcafd46942b10e02943effc4a'
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || ''

module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: 'hardhat',
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    sepolia: {
      url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY],
      chainId: 11155111,
    },
    localhost: {
      url: 'http://localhost:8545',
      chainId: 31337,
    },
  },
  solidity: '0.8.19',
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: true,
    currency: 'USD',
    outputFile: 'gas-report.txt',
    noColors: true,
    coinmarketcap: COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
  },
}
package.json : 
```dart
  
{
  "name": "hardhat_simple_storage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/abi": "^5.7.0",
    "@ethersproject/providers": "^5.7.2",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.5",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.7",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.3",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.1.1",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.4",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.12.3",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.22",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.2",
    "typechain": "^8.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
````

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "hardhat_simple_storage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ethersproject/abi": "^5.7.0",
    "@ethersproject/providers": "^5.7.2",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^1.0.5",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.7",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.3",
    "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^10.1.1",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^6.1.4",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.12.3",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.22",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.2",
    "typechain": "^8.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```